# Get some space on top when scrolling to a <h2 id="..."> link

Tags: html, hyperlink

On a html page I have a link like:

```
<a href="/page.htm#something">
```

The other page (page.htm) looks like:

```
<h1>header</h1>
<p>some text</p>

<H2 id="something">The header 2</H2>
etc.
```

When I follow the link to page.htm#something then the header2 is exactly on top of the browser.

My wish is that I get some room abow it, let's say 1em or so.

Of course I can use:

```
<a name="something"><br /></a>
<H2>The header 2</H2>
```

But that's so ugly and needs a lot more typing.

Is there a way that this link is somewhat positioned lower in the webbrowser?

Answer (score 0):

```
<H2 style="padding-top:20px">The header 2</H2>
```

I understood you?

Comment: Margin will not work, because it is out of the box model. Instead, use padding instead.

Comment: @Terry so padding-top?

Comment: Nicael, that will influence my page layout.
I have chosen to have (almost) no padding-top or margin-top only in my design, only padding-bottom and margin-bottom.
My feeling says that there must be another way, can't imagine that I'm the only one that complains about this ugly "top of page" alignment.